# Unexplained space in QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

I have a `QFrame` and `QTableWidget` built-in in `QFrame`. When I `drag` my `QTableWidget` I see an extra space such as the following picture. I put a circle in picture. My project is `RTL` : `Right To Left`.

**Question:** How i solve my unexplained space?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the extra space that the table view didn't need for your columns in its current state. You can have the last column fill all available remaining space by setting the [stretchLastSection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop) property to true. I believe it's an option in designer, or you can do it programatically:

```
myTable->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```